# zcat stdout pipe vs gzip module

Tags: python, pipe, gzip

I've written a python function which read from a text file compressed with gzip.
I've used the gzip module to read the file, here is the code:

```
def apertura(file):
    diz_pagerank = {}
    with gzip.open(file) as pagerank_file:
        pagerank_csv = csv.reader(pagerank_file, delimiter='\t')
        for pagerank in pagerank_csv:
            diz_pagerank[pagerank[0]] = float(pagerank[1])
    return diz_pagerank
```

I've read the gzip module is really slow compared with zcat. I've measured the time used to execute:
time:
real    1m31.112s
user    1m29.420s
sys     0m1.684s

I've rewritten the code to use the subprocess module, using directly zcat to open the file:

```
def apertura(file):
    diz_pagerank = {}
    process = subprocess.Popen(['zcat', file], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    for pagerank in iter(process.stdout.readline, ''): 
        pagerank = pagerank.strip().split('\t')
        diz_pagerank[pagerank[0]] = float(pagerank[1])
    return diz_pagerank
```

But now the function is much slower!
This is the result of time:
real    5m26.536s
user    2m19.976s
sys     3m11.904s

How can it be possible? Where am I doing wrong? Other tips to speed up things?

Comment: The communication with the child process needs two extra system calls (write+read) per block (one for the child one for the parent) Plus 2 extra context switches.

Comment: The two functions are very different. Using zcat to capture output is faster than using gzip.open, benchmark just capturing the output to see it. Youn need to benchmark each part of the functions to see which bit is taking the time. The easiest way to do that is spit it up into individual functions and benchmark them all.